# "No Hibernate Session bound to thread", transactional method breaks execution of the next transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions

My problem is hidden in class, with 2 methods.

```
@Repository
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public class RetentionController {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        ...

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public BaseResource getResource(String pPath)throws ResourceNotFoundException{
        ...
        Criteria critDirExists = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Directory.class);
        critDirExists.add(Restrictions.eq(PATH, pPath));
        Directory dir = (Directory) critDirExists.uniqueResult();

        ...processing results...
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void addDirectory(String pPath) {

        modelValidator.validateDirectoryURI(pPath);

        //check if such exists
        Criteria critExists = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Directory.class);
        critExists.add(Restrictions.eq("path", pPath));
        ...
     }

...
}
```

SessionFactory is injected correctly - first method executes normally. The problem is:
addDirectory throws "No Hibernate Session bound to thread" at " Criteria critExists = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Directory.class);", when it is invoked after "getResource()" method.

Logs (I added marks to see where methods are started and finished: GET RESOURCE: START/END, ADD DIRECTORY: START/END):

```
  DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
  DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager] - Creating new transaction with name [com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.dal.RetentionController.getResource]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
  DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager] - Opened new Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@1be3bb2] for Hibernate transaction
  DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager] - Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@1be3bb2]
  DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - Setting JDBC Connection [jdbc:sqlserver://******\****:****;selectMethod=direct;lastUpdateCount=true;, UserName=*********, Microsoft SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver] read-only
  DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager] - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [jdbc:sqlserver://******\****:****;selectMethod=direct;lastUpdateCount=true;, UserName=*********, Microsoft SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver]
  TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] - Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@13b8f62] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@115512] to thread [http-9080-1]
  TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] - Bound value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@299629] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1429498] to thread [http-9080-1]
  TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] - Initializing transaction synchronization
  TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] - Getting transaction for [com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.dal.RetentionController.getResource]
  DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.aspect.TraceLog#0'
  DEBUG [com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.dal.RetentionController] - ---GET RESOURCE: START
  TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@299629] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1429498] bound to thread [http-9080-1]
  DEBUG [com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.dal.RetentionController] - Getting ILM object: /CADPWebDAV
  DEBUG [com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.dal.RetentionController] - RequestType is MKCOL
  DEBUG [com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.dal.RetentionController] - EmbryoResource was created.
  TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@299629] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1429498] bound to thread [http-9080-1]
  DEBUG [com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.dal.RetentionController] - ---GET RESOURCE: END
  TRACE [com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.aspect.TraceLog] - RetentionController.getResource(..) Executed at: 78 ms
  TRACE [com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.aspect.TraceLog] - Method Argument [1]: com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.servlet.CADPRequest@10241ae
  TRACE [com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.aspect.TraceLog] - Method Argument [2]: com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.tci.TCIWrapper@1ca203
  TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] - Completing transaction for [com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.dal.RetentionController.getResource]
  TRACE [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager] - Triggering beforeCommit synchronization
  TRACE [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager] - Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
  DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager] - Initiating transaction commit
  DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager] - Committing Hibernate transaction on Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@1be3bb2]
  TRACE [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager] - Triggering afterCommit synchronization
  TRACE [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager] - Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
  TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] - Clearing transaction synchronization
  TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] - Removed value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@299629] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1429498] from thread [http-9080-1]
  TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] - Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@13b8f62] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@115512] from thread [http-9080-1]
  DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager] - Closing Hibernate Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@1be3bb2] after transaction
  DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils] - Closing Hibernate Session
  DEBUG [com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.dal.RetentionController] - ---ADD DIRECTORY: START
  DEBUG [com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.dal.RetentionController] - Validation: OK
  DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils] - Opening Hibernate Session
  DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils] - Closing Hibernate Session
  ERROR [com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.servlet.CADPServlet] - org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

Spring configuration xml file:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:spring.properties"/>

<context:annotation-config/>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<context:mbean-export/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:mappingResources="CADPWebDAV_hbm.xml">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="eventListeners">
        <map>
            <entry key="merge">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.IdTransferringMergeEventListener"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>'

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
      p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>
```

Here is the StackTrace of the exception:

```
[com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.servlet.CADPServlet] - org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

[com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.servlet.CADPServlet] - org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:63)
[com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.servlet.CADPServlet] - org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:687)
[com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.servlet.CADPServlet] - com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.dal.RetentionController.addDirectory(RetentionController.java:189)
...
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of the stack trace showing that the exception originates from the addDirectory method, from the logs it is not evident that it is from the addDirectory method. The log is associated with the servlet.

Comment: I added StackTrace of the thrown exception - it is definitely 'addDirectory()'.

Comment: Can you check if You are calling the addDirectory method on a object that is retreived from spring (context.getBean or @Autowired). From the logs it looks like the transaction proxy is being bypassed for the  addDirectory call - one reason that can happen is that the object is not a spring bean. You can put a breakpoint and debug - check if the object is really a proxy, if yes why it is not starting a new transaction.

Comment: yes, there is bean:
     `<bean id="decisionsRep" class="com.asg.tciclientadapters.webdav.dal.RetentionController"/>`
and all classes recieves RetentionController either by @autowired field, or by constructor parameter (which leads to class, where it was got by @autowired)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was - to add into web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

After that exception has gone.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to change the @Transactional setting for your addDirectory method to the following:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

Based upon my understanding of how the transaction management process works in Spring/Hibernate, your current setup tells hibernate that you are going to execute everything as read-only so when you try to do it in a non-read-only manner it blows up.  I found supporting documentation for this at:  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation

I'm assuming that if you call your addDirectory method prior to getResource then your code works.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but these methods are invoked by another class, so transaction is not propagated. I thought that maybe it stayed not finished after first method (and so tried to flush it before returning result), but it contradicts the essence of @transactional annotation. Also I had to mention - i use Spring3.0

Comment: Sorry for directing you to the old doc... I have updated my original post so that it goes to the 3.0 version instead of 2.0.  I don't have any additional suggestions though, when you figure it out I hope you will post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the versions of Hibernate don't quite align in the class attributes.

The transactionManager class org.springframework.orm.hibernate**X** must match the SessionFactory class org.springframework.orm.hibernate**X** version, which also needs to be supported by the version you've used in your maven dependency.